# Create chart with x and y coordinates

Tags: reactjs, web, plot, coordinates

I want to display X and Y coordinates on the site
however, throw this error?
Does anyone know what this could be?
It may be because it does not display
I work in react js
[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM8mQ.png)

[source code_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDDK8.png)

[source code_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CArpn.png)

Comment: It's hard to give you an answer without seeing the code. Can you show us some more code?

Comment: Of course, 
I added 2 images of source code

Comment: my guess is that your init_connection() method does setState, and since it gets called in the constructor you get that error

Comment: Why don't you display the data?
I looked from a pumpkin similar code, maybe you could help with that?

Comment: Post actual code here. Not pictures